# IPv6 Wireguard ULA Routing

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, forwarding, wireguard

I would like to route traffic between two devices when they're both on NAT connections. They are both connected to a wireguard VPN on a VPS, but they cannot ping each other.

On their wireguard interfaces, I have assigned the address `fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1` to the VPS, `fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::1` to Alice, and `fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::1` to Bob.

The routing tables are:

Alice:

```
liam@alice# ip -6 route show dev wg0
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::/64 proto static metric 50 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::/64 via fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1 metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 proto kernel metric 50 pref medium
ff00::/8 metric 256 pref medium
```

Bob:

```
liam@bob# ip -6 route show dev wg0
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::/64 via fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::/64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

VPS:

```
liam@vps# ip -6 route show dev wg0
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::/64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:2::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:3::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:4::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::/64 metric 1024 pref medium
```

IPv6 forwarding is enabled on the VPS:

```
liam@vps# sysctl net.ipv6.conf.wg0.forwarding
net.ipv6.conf.wg0.forwarding = 1
```

and all ip6tables are empty with policy ACCEPT:

```
liam@{vps,alice,bob}# ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Alice and Bob can ping the VPS, but they cannot ping each other:

```
liam@alice# ping fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1
PING fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1(fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=31.8 ms
^C
liam@alice# ping fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::1
PING fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::1(fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::1) 56 data bytes
From fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

```
liam@bob# ping fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1
PING fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1(fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=58.3 ms
^C
liam@bob# ping fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::1
PING fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::1(fd0d:87fa:c3bc:5::1) 56 data bytes
From fd0d:87fa:c3bc:6::1 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

What steps have I missed to get IPv6 traffic routed though wireguard?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `AllowedIPs` wireguard setting of the VPS allows the IPs of other clients though the interface.

Replace line starting with `-` with the line starting with `+` in Alice and Bob's wireguard .conf files:

```
 [Peer]
 PublicKey = {redacted-vps-public-key}
-AllowedIPs = fd0d:87fa:c3bc:1::/64
+AllowedIPs = fd0d:87fa:c3bc::/48
 Endpoint = {vps-wireguard-uri}
 PersistentKeepalive = 60
```